# When debugging node.js code in IntelliJ 2020, saw error: Error running 'app.js': com/sun/javafx/runtime/FXObject

Tags: node.js, debugging, intellij-idea, javafx, upgrade

I recently upgraded my IntelliJ from 15 to 2020. When debugging node.js code, the debug tab didn't show correctly. I saw an error message: Error running 'app.js': com/sun/javafx/runtime/FXObject

[Please refer to the below link to see the error I saw:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjdGC.png)

Please let me know if you have any idea about this issue.

Thanks,
Jane

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the JRE you run the IDE with doesn't include javafx; please try using the bundled JBR instead (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under)
If it doesn't help, please try disabling `js.debugger.webconsole` key in the **Registry** (**Help > Find action...**, type `registry...` to locate it)

Comment: It works after I did what you suggested. Thanks so much for your help!